# Include datatable in highcharts pdf rendering

Tags: javascript, canvas, highcharts

I render a highcharts chart from a table of data, which I then include at the bottom of the chart as a HTML `<table>`. Is there a way I can render this table in the highcharts `<canvas>` so it gets included in the PDF rendering system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this entry in the Highcharts FAQ:

- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table

With this `example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/